# vue-router this.$route object is always empty with single file components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am using single file components with vue-router and vue-2.0 and I am having an issue I can't seem to be able to resolve. The `this.$route` object called from a component always returns empty values.

e.g.

[image]

**Messages.vue**

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Post List</div>

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <li v-for="item in items">
                            {{ item.message }}
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        created() {
            console.log(this.$route);
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },
        data() {
            return {
                items: [
                    {message: 'Foo'},
                    {message: 'Bar'}
                ]
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

**App.js**

```html
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Messages from './components/Messages';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    { path: '/user/get/:id', component: Messages},
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
})

const app = new Vue({
    router,
    el: '#app',
    components: { Messages }
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which is the url you are using in your browser? if it is `/` I think it is working propertly. Try to put `?parameter=1` in the end of your url and check if the `query` in the router changes

Comment: @EvaldoBratti url is `user/get/2`

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve it? None of the answers below seemed to understand the issue. I can solve it with a `settimeout` but that's not a good solution

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tell Vue here to render the router views you can do this by modifying the Vue initialization by adding a template that holds the route-view directive.

```
const app = new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  template: '<router-view/>',
  components: { Messages }
})
```

That should make it work for you.

Comment: This just redirects me to a blank page. I just need to be able to get access to this.$route so i can extract the url parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know what the problem is because you haven't included the HTML representing the template that the root component uses to render.

If your root component is rendering a `router-view` component then the route params should be available in the `Messages` component instance.

Here is an example using your setup: https://codepen.io/autumnwoodberry/pen/WEBEKd?editors=1010